# jquery libraries conflict

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the following libraries in my project

1. `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`
2. `<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>`
3. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
4. `<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

there is a conflict between first 2 and second 2 libraries when I use first 2 then 3 and 4 stop working.

I could not fix this conflict.

Comment: you must have 1 jquery script , include latest

Comment: The conflict is between #1 and #3. Remove #3 and make sure #1 is referencing the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: You can't keep two different versions of Jquery, remove the #3

Comment: Remove 1st one and put 3rd one instead of 1st and then try.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have multiple jquery files included, this should be avoided. Use the latest version and include it at top before any other library, as other plugins are dependent on jquery library, try excluding the 3rd number jquery file, otherwise include latest jquery library and then datetimepicker and autocomplete:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: check  console for errors using developers tools in chrome or firebug in firefox